# Chord Progression "Time" - Hans Zimmer

Tags: chord-theory, analysis

I was taking a look at the soundtrack for the Inception movie:"Time" by Hans Zimmer.
Does anyone understand what kind of a weird progression he uses?

I tried everything from cadential to sequential but I can't seem to find an explanation.

The Track is in Gmajor/Eminor and the progression goes as follows:
Amin-Emin-G-D

Check this for the score:https://analysemusic.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/musical-analysis-time-hans-zimmer-page-0012.jpg

Hans Zimmer started out in pop music so he just repeats this progression, the production is the best part though, take a listen if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 10):

You list G major and E minor as possible tonics, but I'm going to go a different direction: I hear this in A! As such, with one sharp in the key signature, it's really more of an A Dorian. Thus the progression is `i v VII IV`.

(Perhaps the very ambiguity of tonic was intentional, considering what takes place in the movie and the title of the piece.)

The `i` moving to `v` is clear enough, I think; it's just tonic moving to dominant. The only odd part is that the `v` is minor, but this is standard in the Dorian mode.

The `VII` is really a dominant substitute in Dorian, so that chord makes sense as well. At that point, Zimmer just moves around the circle of fourths to get back to tonic: `VII` moves down a fourth (=up a fifth) to `IV`, which then moves down a fourth (up a fifth) to `i`.

Note that that's different from the typical circle of fifths which goes down a *fifth* (=up a *fourth*). This may be Zimmer's popular music influence, since the circle of descending fourths is very common in that repertoire.

Another, perhaps simpler, explanation is as two related perfect fifths: `i` moves to `v`, and that ascending fifth is moved down a second to create `VII` moving to `IV`.

We can extend this further theoretically, if we want to, by saying that the upper fifth is just an extension of the original chord. In other words, the `v` is just an extension of `i`, and `IV` is just an extension of `VII`, so we can reduce this progression to just `i VII`, which is a very common move.

Comment: Thanks, definetly the best explanation I've heard yet :)

Comment: But it isn't an explanation, just a description.

Comment: Hate to be nit-picky here but the circle of 5ths goes “up” while the circle of 4ths goes “down”. Shapes of tetrachords and all that.

Comment: is 'extension' another word for prolongation?

Comment: and how do you 'hear' something in dorian?